# How to calculate the winding number?

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, winding-number

I've been given the following loop $\gamma$, which clearly divides the complex plain into 5 domains. For each of these domains, I have been asked to find the winding number of $a$ around $\gamma$, where $a$ is a point in the domain.

[image]

Since I haven't been given any further information of the loop, I don't think I can use the formula $$n(\gamma,a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-a}$$ now intuitively I know that the winding numbers of the domain outside the loop is $0$, the domain in the centre is, I'm guessing, $2$ and for the remaining domains is $1$. But nowhere have I  been able to find a good explanation for winding number apart from the aforementioned formula (and the proof that it will be an integer)[Resources consulted: Couple of Lecture Notes online, this website, and books by Lang, Ahlfors and Bak-Newman]. Can someone please give me an explanation on how I can find the winding number in situations like these? I haven't yet been taught the Cauchy Integral Formula.

Comment: Is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703695/crazy-calculation-for-winding-numbers/704176#704176 of some help?

Comment: This is very similar to an application of Ampère's law (integral form) in which the path has the topology of a trefoil knot. When you have a current going through the central part of the path you get a different value from the lobes. You can then apply Ampere's law again to break the closed path in two disjoint open paths where you know the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You left out a vital piece of information: that little arrow on the left, pointing down. It tells you in which direction the loop is travelled (only once, I assume). Therefore, the winding number of each point of the three lobes is $1$ and in the central region it is equal to $2$. I suggest that you read this [intuitive description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Intuitive_description) of the winding number.

Comment: Thanks! This sort of an intuitive description is exactly what I was looking for, though I don't know how I missed the Wikipedia entry on the topic.

Comment: @junkquill I'm glad I could help.