# How do you define the 'inside' of a shape.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let ***A, B, C*** be distinct non-collinear points on the Euclidean plane.

Let ***D*** be a point between ***B*** and ***C***.

How, only by strictly working with the axioms for Geometry, can you show that ***AD*** goes *'inside'* the triangle ***ABC***?.

Do I have to treat the triangle as a set of points and to show parametrically that every point on the segment of ***AD*** is a member of the set defined by ***ABC***?

More generally, how is it common to define the term - *'inside'*?.

Comment: This is a non-trivial issue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). There are technical solutions using complex functions theory with $\int_{\gamma} dz/(z-a)=2 \pi \iff \ a $ is inside closed contour $\gamma$.

Comment: @Jean Marie 
thank you so much!

Comment: @Jean Marie I figured this was going to be something really complex

Comment: I appreciate your humor...

Comment: The *cutting number* may be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703695/crazy-calculation-for-winding-numbers/704176#704176

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: how is it defined for a point *on* the curve ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The wikipedia article states: "It is easy to establish this result for polygons".

Comment: Indeed, there is an algorithm (cutting number algorithm) as given by Michael Hoppe; I was forgetting it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, the cutting is defined only for points not on the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pasch's Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom) states that, if a line $l$ intersects $\triangle ABC$ on the side $\overline{AB}$ between its endpoints, but does not contain $A$, $B$, or $C$, then $l$ intersects precisely one of $\overline{AC}$ or $\overline{BC}$ between its endpoints. Pasch's Axiom is [Hilbert's Axiom II.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms).

Using Pasch's axiom, it is possible to define half-planes. Namely, each line $l$ separates the plane into two convex sets, called half-planes, such that $A$ and $B$ are in the same half-plane if and only if $\overline{AB}$ does not intersect $l$, and in opposite half-planes if and only if $\overline{AB}$ does intersect $l$.

The interior of the angle $\angle BAC$ is defined as the intersection of two half-planes: the half-plane of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ containing $C$, and the half-plane of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ containing $B$. As the intersection of two convex sets, the interior of the angle is itself convex.

The interior of the triangle may then be defined as the intersection of the interiors of its three angles.

Now consider $\triangle ABC$ and a point $D$ between $B$ and $C$. Note that the segment $\overline{CD}$ does not intersect the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, because the line $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ at $B$, hence cannot intersect $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ at a point between $C$ and $D$. Similarly, the segment $\overline{BD}$ does not intersect the line $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$. It follows that $D$ is in the interior of $\angle BAC$.

$\hspace{3 cm}$[image]

Let $E$ be any point between $A$ and $D$. $E$ is on $\overrightarrow{AD}$, so $E$ is in the interior of $\angle BAC$. If it were not, then, since $D$ is in the interior, the segment $\overline{DE}$ would have to intersect either $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ or $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, but the line $\overleftrightarrow{DE}$ intersects each line at $A$, hence cannot intersect either at a point between $D$ and $E$.

Now consider $\angle ABC$. $\overline{DE}$ does not intersect $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, as just explained, so $E$ is in half-plane of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ containing $D$. It follows that $E$ and $C$ are in the same half-plane of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ as well. On the other hand, the segment $\overline{AE}$ does not intersect $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$, because the line $\overleftrightarrow{AE}$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ at $D$, hence cannot intersect $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ at any point between $A$ and $E$. It follows that $E$ is in the half-plane of $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ containing $A$. So $E$ is in the interior of $\angle ABC$.

Similarly, $E$ is in the interior of $\angle CAB$.

Because $E$ is in the interior of each of the three angles, it must be in the interior of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Isn't the question about $D$ ?

Comment: The question as I read it was about $\overline{AD}$. I.e., how does one show that $\overline{AD}$ is in the interior of $\triangle ABC$? And how does one define the interior of $\triangle ABC$ in the first place, in terms of the axioms of geometry?

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That is CRAZY cool!!

Comment: No prob, @EliyahuAbadi. If it works for you, do me a solid and [accept it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)!

Comment: Gladly accepted :)