# Calculate the integral for winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I want to find the winding number of the closed curve $\gamma(t)=\frac{-1}{2}+\cos(3t)+i\sin(4t)$ at point $0$ ; where $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. For that, we have to find the value of

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{-3\sin(3t)+4i\cos(4t)}{\frac{-1}{2}+\cos(3t)+i\sin(4t)}dt. $$

I have no idea how to find the above integral. Also the given closed curve is too complex to visualise so we can't find the the winding number geometrically at $0$. Is there any simpler method to find the integral or winding number of the above curve at $0$ ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about drawing and counting *cutting numbers*, see [Crazy calculation for winding numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703695/crazy-calculation-for-winding-numbers/704176#704176)?

[image]

Hence the winding number is $-1$.